# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object- not passing any data

Tags: java, android, backendless

I'm working on backendless, here I'm saving an object in database, then i start the new activity but it shows the error. currently, i'm not passing any data between activities but still getting the error.here is my code

```
    MessageThreads newThread = new MessageThreads();
                        newThread.setUser1(user);
                        newThread.setUser2(currentUser);
                        ChatMessages message = new ChatMessages();
                        message.setCreator(currentUser);
                        message.setText("Hello");
                        List<ChatMessages> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(message);
                        newThread.setMessages(list);
                      Backendless.Data.of(MessageThreads.class).save(newThread, new AsyncCallback<MessageThreads>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleResponse(MessageThreads response) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                response.setDialogName(user.getProperty("name").toString());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SingleMessageActivity.class);
//                                intent.putExtra("threadId", response.getObjectId());
//                                intent.putExtra("name", response.getDialogName());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                                makeToast("error in loading messages");
                            }
                        });
```

and here is my error trace

```
 Process: com.example.mubtadanaqvi.stunexus, PID: 30625
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.backendless.BackendlessUser)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1323)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
                                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1140)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:564)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1292)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1211)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
                                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2755)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3313)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1366)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:981)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1076)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1406)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
                                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1318)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1140) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:564) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1292) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1211) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2755) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3313) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

chatMessages Model:

```
    package com.example.mubtadanaqvi.stunexus;

import com.backendless.BackendlessUser;
import com.stfalcon.chatkit.commons.models.IMessage;
import com.stfalcon.chatkit.commons.models.IUser;

import java.util.Date;

import weborb.service.ExcludeProperties;


@ExcludeProperties(propertyNames = {"createdAt", "id","user"})
public class ChatMessages implements IMessage
{
  private java.util.Date created;
  private String objectId;
  private String text;
  private java.util.Date updated;
  private String ownerId;
  private BackendlessUser creator;

  private String id;
  private IUser user;
  private Date date;

  public java.util.Date getCreated()
  {
    return created;
  }
  public String getObjectId()
  {
    return objectId;
  }
  public void setText( String text )
  {
    this.text = text;
  }
  public java.util.Date getUpdated()
  {
    return updated;
  }
  public String getOwnerId()
  {
    return ownerId;
  }
  public BackendlessUser getCreator()
  {
    return creator;
  }
  public void setCreator( BackendlessUser creator )
  {
    this.creator = creator;
  }

  public String getText()
  {
    return text;
  }

  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return getObjectId();
  }
  public void setId(String id){
    this.id=id;
  }
  @Override
  public IUser getUser() {
    DialogAuthor user = new DialogAuthor();
    user.setId(getObjectId());
    user.setName(getCreator().getProperty("name").toString());
    user.setAvtar(null);
    return user;
  }
  public void setUser(IUser user){
    this.user=user;
  }
  @Override
  public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return getCreated();
  }
  public void setCreatedAt(Date d){
    this.date=d;
  }

}//class
```

Backendless User class is builtin and here is the code :

```
    /*
 * ********************************************************************************************************************
 *  <p/>
 *  BACKENDLESS.COM CONFIDENTIAL
 *  <p/>
 *  ********************************************************************************************************************
 *  <p/>
 *  Copyright 2012 BACKENDLESS.COM. All Rights Reserved.
 *  <p/>
 *  NOTICE: All information contained herein is, and remains the property of Backendless.com and its suppliers,
 *  if any. The intellectual and technical concepts contained herein are proprietary to Backendless.com and its
 *  suppliers and may be covered by U.S. and Foreign Patents, patents in process, and are protected by trade secret
 *  or copyright law. Dissemination of this information or reproduction of this material is strictly forbidden
 *  unless prior written permission is obtained from Backendless.com.
 *  <p/>
 *  ********************************************************************************************************************
 */

package com.backendless;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public final class BackendlessUser implements Serializable
{
  private final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public static final String PASSWORD_KEY = "password";
  public static final String EMAIL_KEY = "email";
  public static final String ID_KEY = "objectId";

  public BackendlessUser()
  {
  }

  /**
   * Returns a COPY of user's properties
   * (this means if you modify the return value, actual user properties won't be modified)
   *
   * @return a COPY of this user's properties
   */
  public Map<String, Object> getProperties()
  {
    return new HashMap<String, Object>( properties );
  }

  public void setProperties( Map<String, Object> properties )
  {
    synchronized( this )
    {
      this.properties.clear();
      putProperties( properties );
    }
  }

  public void putProperties( Map<String, Object> properties )
  {
    synchronized( this )
    {
      this.properties.putAll( properties );
    }
  }

  public Object getProperty( String key )
  {
    synchronized( this )
    {
      if( properties == null )
        return null;

      return properties.get( key );
    }
  }

  public void setProperty( String key, Object value )
  {
    synchronized( this )
    {
      properties.put( key, value );
    }
  }

  public String getObjectId()
  {
    return getUserId();
  }

  public String getUserId()
  {
    Object result = getProperty( ID_KEY );

    return result == null ? null : String.valueOf( result );
  }

  public void setPassword( String password )
  {
    setProperty( PASSWORD_KEY, password );
  }

  public String getPassword()
  {
    Object result = getProperty( PASSWORD_KEY );

    return result == null ? null : String.valueOf( result );
  }

  public void setEmail( String email )
  {
    setProperty( EMAIL_KEY, email );
  }

  public String getEmail()
  {
    Object result = getProperty( EMAIL_KEY );

    return result == null ? null : String.valueOf( result );
  }

  public void clearProperties()
  {
    synchronized( this )
    {
      properties.clear();
    }
  }

  public Object removeProperty( String key )
  {
    return properties.remove( key );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals( Object o )
  {
    if( this == o )
      return true;

    if( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() )
      return false;

    BackendlessUser that = (BackendlessUser) o;

    if( !properties.equals( that.properties ) )
      return false;

    return true;
  }

  private Object marker;// = new Object();

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    Set<Object> refCache = new HashSet<Object>(  );
    return hashCode( refCache );
  }

  private int hashCode(Set<Object> refCache)
  {
    if( marker != null )
      return 0;
    else
      marker = new Object();

    if(refCache.contains( marker ))
      return 0;

    refCache.add( marker );

    int hashCode = 0;

    for( Object value : properties.values() )
    {
      if(value == null)
        continue;

      if(value instanceof BackendlessUser)
        hashCode += ((BackendlessUser) value).hashCode( refCache );
      else
        hashCode += value.hashCode();
    }

    return hashCode;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append( "BackendlessUser{" );

    for( Map.Entry<String, Object> property : properties.entrySet() )
    {
      sb.append( property.getKey() ).append( "=" ).append( property.getValue() ).append( ", " );
    }

    sb.delete( sb.length() - 2, sb.length() );
    sb.append( "}" );

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: do not use serializable with parcelable

Comment: @DivyeshPatel can you please mention, where I am doing wrong in the code.

Comment: post ChatMessages  model class and BackendlessUser.java

Comment: Does the error occur if you comment out the "startActivity" method call?

Comment: No, without start activity it doesn't occur.